# Difference between `type {}` and `Dictionary<T> { [key: string]: T; }`

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

The async library uses this declaration

```
export interface Dictionary<T> { [key: string]: T; }
```

but I am confused, how is this different from

```
type {}
```

?

Perhaps `type {}` allows for Symbol to be used for keys, and the Dictionary interface only allows for keys to be strings?

Here are the typings for async:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/async/index.d.ts#L9

Answer (score 2):

When using `--noImplicitAny`, the *index-signature* in the `Dictionary<T>` interface above will allow arbitrary string-based property access, while `{}` will not, because it does not have an index-signature:

```
interface Dictionary<T> { [key: string]: T; }

let a: Dictionary<string> = {};
let b: {} = {};

a["one"] = "two"; // OK
b["two"] = "three"; // Not OK
```

This is not a problem when `--noImplicitAny` is *not* used, or `--suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` *is* used, because then every object type is treated as having an implicit "any-to-any" index-signature by default.

Comment: Thanks, what about Symbol's though, any thoughts on that?

Comment: Maybe mention the related `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` option, too?

Comment: Perhaps under the hood, Symbol properties are always coerced to Strings?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Symbols enough to answer them, but the index-signature is definitely a difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big and obvious difference in addition to John Weisz's answer: `Dictionary<T>` allows you to specify `T`, `{}` doesn't.